# Get interactive psql shell after executing queries

Tags: psql

I want to execute a set of commands before executing other queries using `psql`

The following is what I want to execute

```
psql << EOF
\setenv PAGER 'pspg -s 0'
\pset pager always
EOF
```

After executing this, I want to have an interactive shell with these parameters set.

I am looking for how to get interactive shell after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`psql` has a built-in feature to set defaults: the [`~/.psqlrc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#id-1.9.4.18.10) file.

You can put any command in there that should be executed when you start `psql`

So just create that file and put:

```
\setenv PAGER 'pspg -s 0'
\pset pager always
```

into it.